# After blocking a website I am getting Reply from 128.116.116.3: Destination port unreachable

Tags: networking, ping

I wanted to block the access to Roblox.com during school time.

I checked the net and found that I can add this site in
`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file. So I added it:

```
0.0.0.0 roblox.com
```

And it worked! The website was blocked and they cannot access it anymore.

It is school holiday in Australia now and I want to give them access back. I removed that line from hosts file but the website still blocked.

I tried restarting the computer and still blocked. I tried ping roblox.com and I am getting this:

```
Reply from 128.116.116.3: Destination port unreachable.
```

I wonder how can I get that website back?!

These are the things I have tried that don’t seem to solve the problem:

- I restarted the computer.
- I restarted the router.
- I tried `ipconfig /flushdns`.

Comment: Flush your DNS?

Comment: @music2myear how to do that?

Comment: @music2myear I used ipconfig /flushdns and got successful flush but the problem still the same nothing fixed

Comment: I cannot ping the IP address 128.116.116.3, it also returns Destination port unreachable, but when I ping robolox.com again 
It returns IP address 199.191.50.73 where 4 packets are successfully reached.

Comment: Why am I getting that IP when I ping roblox.com , maybe its their australian server

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong here, but I expect that what is happening is your computer is trying to send data to `0.0.0.0`, and a server in the path (ie `128.116.116.3`) does not have a default route, and does not have a route for it in its routing table, so its sending back a message to say the destination is unreachable.

Note that `0.0.0.0` is a "special" IP address which should not be routed onto the Internet (but I don't believe it has a defined behaviour in this context as its not valid)  Rather then using `0.0.0.0` to block it, try using `127.0.0.1`, which as per Internet definitions, should always be the IP address of your computer.